# GRUB fail/Damaged partition

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, mount, windows-10

I had a laptop with working dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which has been damaged by a water spillage. After repairing laptop boots straight to Windows 10 (GRUB vanished), so I can't launch ubuntu.
I tried to fix it in several ways:

1. by unchecking the box control panel -> power options -> choose what the power buttons do -> change settings that are currently unavailable -> Turn on fast startup (recommended) (like here: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup)
2. by launching live-usb session with ubuntu 18.04 LTS ("try ubuntu" mode) and typing following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

like here:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

None of the solutions worked. In case 2) there wasn't any "recommendeed repair" button, I could only create a bootinfo summary.Here is the pastebin from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5gdC3PZz3c/

```
boot-repair-4ppa103                                              [20200508_0042]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi 
                       /efi/dell/SOS/bootmgfw.efi /efi/dell/SOS/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/dell/SOS/bootx64.efi /efi/dell/SOS/memtest.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/nvme0n1p7: cannot mount; probably corrupted filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p7.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32784 of /dev/sda1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on nvme0n1p7
OS#2:   Windows on nvme0n1p3

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, bionic, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0006,0005,0001,0002,0003,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,3e6c1d35-407c-4e2d-9d2b-b92d4f9e38e0,0x800,0x145000)/File(FI\Microsoft\Bootootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...K................
Boot0001* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,Diskette Drive,0x0)..BO
Boot0002* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,Generic Flash Disk 8.07,0x0)..BO
Boot0003* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    BBS(CDROM,CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive,0x0)..BO
Boot0004* Onboard NIC   BBS(Network,Onboard NIC,0x0)..BO
Boot0005* UEFI: PC401 NVMe SK hynix 1TB, Partition 1    HD(1,GPT,3e6c1d35-407c-4e2d-9d2b-b92d4f9e38e0,0x800,0x145000)/File(FI\Microsoft\Bootootmgfw.efi)..BO
Boot0006* UEFI: Generic Flash Disk 8.07, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(0,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x8a2f0,0x800,0xeff800)..BO SecureBoot disabled.

f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
bed45d1c9554cea09924d3814cb7c446   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
256fe27540b54b71cf38110338247688   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
0460d855b6d422c080c1de02010c3ffd   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
cb8e4284804d56f058c0e1cf111eeedd   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
3df357ffd0654bb80f2a575485e6e0cc   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
0cb9f3b3c8d825520dde53221387d4ee   nvme0n1p1/dell/SOS/bootmgfw.efi
49050fba765e329db1ca700638c34849   nvme0n1p1/dell/SOS/bootmgr.efi
0cb9f3b3c8d825520dde53221387d4ee   nvme0n1p1/dell/SOS/bootx64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================


Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : GPT,  noBIOSboot, has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p6   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p7   : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  notbiosboot,    no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  notbiosboot,    no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  notbiosboot,    no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  notbiosboot,    no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p6   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  notbiosboot,    no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p7   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  notbiosboot,    no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p7   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 0DC8655E-37D4-454B-8B45-2213F41CE3A1
               Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048    1333247    1331200   650M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    1333248    1595391     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    1595392 1355689983 1354094592 645.7G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 1970089984 1972117503    2027520   990M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 1972117504 1998161919   26044416  12.4G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p6 1998163968 2000408575    2244608   1.1G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p7 1355689984 1970089983  614400000   293G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 7.5 GiB, 8053063680 bytes, 15728640 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0008a2f0
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *     2048 15728639 15726592  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:8053MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk:;
1:1049kB:8053MB:8052MB:fat32::boot, lba;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:PC401 NVMe SK hynix 1TB:;
1:1049kB:683MB:682MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:683MB:817MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:817MB:694GB:693GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
7:694GB:1009GB:315GB:ext4::;
4:1009GB:1010GB:1038MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
5:1010GB:1023GB:13.3GB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
6:1023GB:1024GB:1149MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
└─sda1      vfat     EC2B-0157                            0008a2f0-01                          UBUNTU 18_0 
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     C6D8-B3A2                            3e6c1d35-407c-4e2d-9d2b-b92d4f9e38e0 ESP         EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               0283a1e6-e8aa-4b45-9870-8ef5946a7a2e             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     060E26390E262263                     491a5599-aead-4ea4-86e3-8b796b50dbe9 OS          Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     8CA00118A0010A82                     5492e920-6ff2-4303-a9b0-29b9274e7105 WINRETOOLS  
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     A410019D10017816                     ab8e8c80-ca6d-4263-93f3-358de1396323 Image       
├─nvme0n1p6 ntfs     121A17A31A1782C1                     efcc2555-11e5-4071-94f5-b6acb5ada1d8 DELLSUPPORT 
└─nvme0n1p7 ext4     8519d044-4c5f-4444-b36e-ab625d82182b b09b8d08-d179-43b8-a9d5-2fb70dd5becf             

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

           Avail Use% Mounted on
nvme0n1p1 556.3M  14% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
nvme0n1p3 271.5G  58% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
nvme0n1p4 470.7M  52% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
nvme0n1p5 231.3M  98% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
nvme0n1p6 467.8M  57% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
sda1        5.5G  26% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1 rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
nvme0n1p3 rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
nvme0n1p4 rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
nvme0n1p5 rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
nvme0n1p6 rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda1      ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 8519d044-4c5f-4444-b36e-ab625d82182b root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Check disc for defects

========================= sda1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[142070]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 18295: /bin/bash

Error code 32
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p7 : Error code 32
Error code 32
mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7

mount -r /dev/nvme0n1p7 : Error code 32
Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  win-legacy-basic-fix
```

There seems to be a problem with mounting:

```
mount: /mnt/BootInfo/nvme0n1p7: cannot mount; probably corrupted filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p7.
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

EDIT 1: I put boot-repair-disk from here(https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) on usb and booted it. This is the outcome: [outcome of boot-repair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgfXl.jpg)

I cannot type any command after that, so my only option is to make a hard shutdown of the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Following steps had to be made:

1. boot live session ubuntu 18.04
2. install gparted (sudo apt-get install gparted) in terminal and run it
3. choose the right partition (nvme0n1p7) and run "check" function
4. finally install boot-repair and click "recommended repair" button

After reboot grub showed normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put Boot Repair(the same tool you are using.  Good choice) on an external CD or USB and then try again.

After that it can be that when Win 10 updates Bios gets messed up. Go in there and fiddle with Legacy, and Secure Boot.  That can help.

Also make sure that the Ubuntu is the top in the boot order.

Comment: Hi, I edited the post concerning your answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I get that a lot.

Comment: Near the top of the BootInfo Summary you see this 

"nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/nvme0n1p7: cannot mount; probably corrupted filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p7."  


Unfortnately that may mean physical corruption.  Not many fixes for that. If you need to recover data then there are lots of tools.